# NVIDIA, is it working on my laptop?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am not sure if my graphics card (nvidia 960m) is it working or not on my laptop. It should be running, considering that the drivers are installed and on the app (NVIDIA X Server Settings) I selected "performance mode". But then again, it is not what the info on the terminal it is saying. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

EDIT 1: Thanks for the reply. I took a screenshot that I hope you will find it interesting.

[image]

EDIT 2 (SOLVED): Since it is solved, I want to share with everyone what I did and how it looks now.

sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'

reboot

Then I went to the software and updates manager, selected on additional drivers the recommended, "apply changes". Then, rebooted again.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can view the install graphics devices in a terminal using this command:
`lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`

You should see output similar to this (I have intel & ATI graphics instead of intel & nvidia but same idea):
[image: shot of lspci output]

Now you have already shown the "system settings" > "details" output in your screenshot that indicates which graphics card is in use. so next you can install the best driver for your nvidia card (the builtin/default driver that comes with the linux kernal for nvidia does not support 3d accel). To do this enter this command in the terminal:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

this will show you the Software & Updates dialog. Use the last tab called "Additional Drivers" to see a list of drivers for your nvidia card including the one being used, and the proprietary drivers. Choose the one with the highest version.  NOTE: you can also run the terminal command `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` to get the recommended best driver.

after selecting/installing the best driver for your card you should reboot.

You have already shown the prime profiles dialog for nvidia. You can use terminal commands to control which card is being used:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia 
sudo prime-select intel

prime-select query
```

The last command will tell you which prime profile is being used.

[further information](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just took a screenshot. I hope to get your comments to understand what I am seeing on screen.

Comment: based on your screenshot (though it looks like you have it working) you need to specify which nvidia driver to install/use. which looks like what you did using the additional drivers tab i mentioned. the lspci command results show only the intel device which means you needed to specify the driver (or reinstall it) for nvidia, which it looks like you did.  glad you got it working!

Comment: Indeed it worked. Thanks a lot. Cheers.